# Filemaker PHP getContainerURL

Tags: php, filemaker

I am trying to get my project-detail.php file to display the contents of a container field in Filemaker.  The contents are always a pdf.  Here is what I have, everything is working except the container field (MasterReport):  I am getting nothing basically, just blank space after `echo '<b>Verifier:</b> &nbsp;' . $projectStaff . '<br>';`

NOTE: I am aware I should update $r to $result and change my query command away from $q, this is in early development and I will make those changes after I have my feet under me.

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('./includes/php/include_master.php');

if ($_SESSION['authenticated'] == "true") {

$id_account = $_SESSION['ID_Account'];
$projectId = $_GET['id'];

$q = $protoFM['EMGSV'] -> newFindCommand('web_projects');
$q -> addFindCriterion('id_account', '=='.$id_account);
$q -> addFindCriterion('ID_Project', $projectId);
$r = $q->execute();

if(FileMaker::isError($r)){

    if($r->code == 401){
        echo "No projects found.";
    }else{
        echo "Unknown Error:".$r->code;
    }

}else{
    foreach ($r->getRecords() as $project){
$projectName = $project->getField('Project_Name');
$projectDate = $project->getField('Date_Start');
$projectStaff = $project->getField('Staff');
$projectReport = $project->getField('MasterReport');
        echo '<b>Affidavit:</b> &nbsp;' . $projectId . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Project Name:</b> &nbsp;' . $projectName . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Project Date:</b> &nbsp;' . $projectDate . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Verifier:</b> &nbsp;' . $projectStaff . '<br>';
        echo $projectReport->getField('MasterReport').'<br>';
        echo '<embed src="' . $fm->getContainerDataURL($projectReport->getField('MasterReport')) .'">';
    }

}

} else {
echo "You are not logged in.";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this to work via the following:

```
foreach ($r->getRecords() as $project){
$projectName = $project->getField('Project_Name');
$projectDate = $project->getField('Date_Start');
$projectStaff = $project->getField('Staff');
$projectReport = $project->getField('MasterReport');
        echo '<b>Affidavit:</b> &nbsp;' . $projectId . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Project Name:</b> &nbsp;' . $projectName . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Project Date:</b> &nbsp;' . $projectDate . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Verifier:</b> &nbsp;' . $projectStaff . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Report Link:</b> &nbsp;' . "<a href='includes/php/containerBridge.php?path=".urlencode($projectReport)."'>Click here to download PDF Report</a><br>";
    }
```

The containerBridge.php file is:

```
<?php
//require_once("FileMaker.php");
include 'include_master.php';
header('Content-Type: application/x-gzip');
header('Content-disposition: filename="DownloadedReport.pdf.gz"');
echo $protoFM['EMGSV']->getContainerData($_GET['path']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Filemaker container fields are a bit different... perhaps thinking outside the box have you tried the reverse, letting filemaker do the php? This can be done using the filemaker '`[SmartPill PHP][1]`' plugin, allowing you to create php control and output from filemaker. I know they have a set of commands handling container fields.